# Is there a way to create a database and extract data from it through a command?

Tags: datatool, database, extract

I have looked up packages such as datatool, but I am not quite sure if they would be able to perform this function. The basic idea is that I would like to have a database similar to a bibtex file, something in which I can put entries like this:

```
entry{bread
calories=78
frenchname=pain}

entry{egg
calories=79
frenchname=oeuf}
```

and somewhere in the tex file I am using I could have some function like:

```
\extract{dataset}{entryname}{data}
```

such that if I put in

```
\extract{mydata}{bread}{frenchname}
```

the resulting file would come up with "pain".

I don't know if there is an easy solution for this, the packages I've looked at list certain ways of expressing data but not in a way that seems intuitive in-text. Is there a way to do this/a direction or package I should look at? I would also be fine working with a comma separated list, but I'd still want to be able to input the name of the value type (e.g. frenchname) in order to get the resulting datapoint (e.g. pain).

Comment: Would you be open to a LuaLaTeX solution? Unrelated: French for egg is 'oeuf'.

Comment: I would be open to a LuaLaTeX solution, as long as it would work with a document that was otherwise written for LaTeX! And thanks, just edited it to oeuf.

Comment: If I had time, I would look into https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple .

Comment: Does the database need to be bibtexish, or would csv work?